# What is the same expression with dropDuplicate in spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to change scala code to fully sql query. but I got stuck due to `dropDuplicate`

what I want to do is change this scala code to Spark sql query

```
df.select($"col1", $"col2", $"col3", $"col4").dropDuplicate($"col1", $"col2", $"col3")
```

But I can't find any clue of this. thanks guys

Edit:
I have this sample data

```
url        | referrer | user | score
google.com | bing.com | a    | 2.1
google.com | bing.com | a    | 3.9
google.com | bing.com | b    | 7.1
google.com | bing.com | c    | 0.8
google.com | bing.com | c    | 9.3
```

what I want to do is

```
url        | referrer | user | score
google.com | bing.com | a    | 3.9 //choose any score of same url, referrer, user
google.com | bing.com | b    | 7.1
google.com | bing.com | c    | 0.8 //choose any score of same url, referrer, user
```

what I know is use window function with row_number

```
select url, referrer, user, score from (
    select url, referrer, user, score, row_number() over(partition by url, referrer, user order by url, referrer user) as rowNum
) where rowNum = 1
```

But Not sure there is better way for this

Comment: sample data and the expected output would help

Comment: @Vamsi Prabhala thanks, I added

Comment: sql you have is fine..just change the order by clause to `order by score`

Comment: I would do  `select first(col4) group by col1,col2,col3`....

Comment: Select all groupBy user and limit one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> you can follow this approach to solve your problem. instead of using row_number and where clause together might cause slow performance.

```
scala> spark.sql("select  distinct url,referrer,user,FIRST_VALUE(score) over(partition by url,referrer,user order by user) score  from sqltable").show
+----------+--------+----+-----+
|       url|referrer|user|score|
+----------+--------+----+-----+
|google.com|bing.com|   b|  7.1|
|google.com|bing.com|   c|  0.8|
|google.com|bing.com|   a|  2.1|
+----------+--------+----+-----+
```

it will solve the purpose although its always select first value of the combination of the partitioned column.
hope this helps you.

let me know if you have any query related to this if its solve your problem accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below sql query. Just use group by Clause for the url,referrer,user fields and then select max(score).

```
spark.sql("select url,referrer,user,max(score) from sqltable group by url,referrer,user ").show
```